# How do I feed FFMPEG with JPEG images via Named Pipe?

Tags: ffmpeg, named-pipe

Normally you can feed FFMPEG with images from the file system using **-f image2**, but this doesn't work when you have a named pipe as input: FFMPEG complatins that "index in the range 0-4" could not be found. Obviously FFMPEG wants to have images named 0...x, which is not possible with named pipes.

What is the right way to do this with named pipes?

Answer (score 1):

You would probably need `image2pipe` instead of `image2`.

I find it strange that it isn't documented online, but it's listed in `ffmpeg -formats` anyway.

Comment: This would be a good candidate for a patch (and probably a good way to learn about contributing to FFmpeg for anyone interested).